# MediaRecorder records and makes file but throws Exception

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I have strange problem with my MediaRecorder. It records voice, make a file with recording. But when I want to stop recording using stop() method, it throws IllegalStateException. Generally I have used setMaxDuration() method, so usually I have ending recording using OnInfoListener and it works properly. But I want also to stop MediaRecorder in the OnTouchListener of the ImageView. My code is here:

```
private static String OUTPUT_FILE;

private void prepareRecording() throws Exception {      
    OUTPUT_FILE = "/sdcard/temp.3gpp";      
    File outFile = new File(OUTPUT_FILE);

    if (outFile.exists())
        outFile.delete();       

    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(OUTPUT_FILE);
    recorder.setMaxDuration(10000);
    try {
        recorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    recorder.start();       
}

private void startRecording() {  
     ImageView image = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.image);

     image.post(new Runnable() { 
     @Override
     public void run() {
        try {
                prepareRecording();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();                    
            }   

        image.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (recorder != null)
                    recorder.stop();
                return true;
            }
        });

        recorder.setOnInfoListener(new OnInfoListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {                     
                if (recorder != null && what == 800){
                    recorder.stop();                            
                }                       
            }
        });     

    }});
    }
```

When I have touched the ImageView I have FATAL EXCEPTION java.lang.IllegalStateException at the line with code recorder.stop(). I have tested my code and I have realized that MediaRecorder seems to be not started. Therefore I have IllegalStateException at recorder.stop(). But when recording stops, I can find on my sdcard recording file. Whats wrong with my code?

I have also AnimationDrawable connected to the my image. It works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved my problem. It is necessary to start new thread in onTouch method to avoid eceptions.

```
image.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){                              
                if (recorder != null)                                   
                    recorder.stop();
        }
    };
    thread.start();                             
    return false;
    }
});
```